# String compression using repeated chars count

Tags: python

I'm going through Cracking the Code and there is this question where they ask to write a method for string compression so:

```
aabbccccaa
```

Would become:

```
a2b1c4a2
```

I came up with this:

```
''.join(y+str.count(y) for y in set(str))
```

But my output was:

```
a5c4b1
```

Could someone point me in the clean direction?

Sorry for bad edits, I'm on a cellphone

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `a2b2c4a2`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. You got the idea

Comment: Not sure if you saw it in the question in the book, but you are only supposed to return the compressed string if it is shorter than the original. Something to keep in mind as a simple one line solution may not satisfy this constraint easily.

Comment: @pomtree `min([ ''.join(your code here), original_str ], key=len)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do the work for you:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'aabbccccaa'
>>> ''.join(k + str(sum(1 for x in g)) for k, g in groupby(s))
'a2b2c4a2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd give a modification based on niemmi's answer that is forward and reversible up to 0x200 occurences of a character and is testable for correctness:

```
output = []
for k,g in groupby(txt):
    k = bytes(k,'ascii')
    g = sum(1 for x in g)
    if g > 0xff:
        output.append(b''.join(k,b'0xff'))
        by = bytes([0xff-g])
        output.append(b''.join(k,by))
    else:
        by = bytes([g])
        output.append(b''.join((k,by)))

compressed = b''.join(output)

decompressed = []
for char, count in zip(compressed[::2], compressed[1::2]):
    decompressed.append(chr(char)*count)

decompressed = ''.join(decompressed)
```

The compression can easily be extended up to any number of occurences beyond 0x200 using the above logic, but the decompression always stays the same for use with any number of occurences. The reason for using bytes is so that you can actually get compression if you were to use a file instead of a python datatype. However this is limited to ascii so you will need to preprocess like so:

```
import string
txt = open('to_compress.txt').read()
txt = "".join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, txt))
```

Furthermore, you will want to test that it works.

```
print("Same?", txt == decompressed)
>>> Same? True
```

You may want to install the pip package burrowswheeler, then you can just:

```
to_compress = burrowswheeler.transform(txt)
... compress decompress...
burrowswheeler.inverse(decompressed)
```